# print only specific content in string

Tags: php

is their any way to get the only words in specific  string

the string is

> "Es wurde festgestellt, dass bei Ihrem GerÃ¤t die Funktion "Mein iPhone suchen" eingerichtet ist.
>   Bitte beachten Sie, dass diese Funktion vor Einsendung Ihres GerÃ¤tes zwingend deaktiviert werden muss, um eine Servicebearbeitung zu ermÃ¶glichen!
>   Bitte geben Sie im Anschluss erneut die IMEI- bzw. Seriennummer Ihres Gerätes ein.|error|DN661-7803|APPLE|IPHONE|iPhone 5S 16GB space grey|DNPN2233FFG8|"

i need to echo  only  "iPhone 5S 16GB space grey"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only one example of what the example string will look like, this is next to impossible. However, if the first part of the string will never have a `|`, and the end format will always be as the one above, you can do something like this:

```
$originalString = "blablablablabla|error|DN661-7803|APPLE|IPHONE|iPhone 5S 16GB space grey|DNPN2233FFG8|";
$pieces = explode("|", $originalString); //Split at |
echo $pieces[5]; //Grab 6th piece
```

**Returns:** iPhone 5S 16GB space grey